# jquery mouseover slide down mouseout slide up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a slide down effect to my menu.

But i cant make it if on mouse over slide down and out slide up

```
$('nav.main_menu li').mouseover(function() {
   $('nav.main_menu li:hover ul.sub-menu').slideDown();
});
```

tried with this either

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav.main_menu li").hover(function () {
      $("nav.main_menu li:hover ul.sub-menu").slideDown(500);
     }, function() {
       $("nav.main_menu li:hover ul.sub-menu").slideUp(300);
   });
  });
```

but if i use this on mouseover it starts to jum up and down at the same time

```
    <nav class="main_menu">
                    <ul>

                        <li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-31"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/">Főoldal</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/akciok/">Akciók</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-164" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-164"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/akciok/kiemelt-ajanlat/">Kiemelt ajánlat</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-167" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-167"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/akciok/allando-kedvezmenyek/">Állandó kedvezmények</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/hirek/">Hírek</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/termekek/">Termékek</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/szolgaltatasok/">Szolgáltatások</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-195" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-195"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/szolgaltatasok/szemeszeti-szurovizsgalat/">Szemészeti szűrővizsgálat</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-191" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-191"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/szolgaltatasok/komputeres-szemvizsgalat/">Komputeres szemvizsgálat</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-190" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-190"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/szolgaltatasok/kontaktlencse-illesztes/">Kontaktlencse illesztés</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-189" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-189"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/szolgaltatasok/garanciak/">Garanciák</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-188" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-188"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/szolgaltatasok/3d-s-szemuveglencse-illesztes/">3D-s szemüveglencse illesztés</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-187"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/szolgaltatasok/szemuveg-javitas-tisztitas/">Szemüveg javítás, tisztítás</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-186" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-186"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/szolgaltatasok/ingyenes-uv-teszt/">Ingyenes UV teszt</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-185" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-185"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/szolgaltatasok/ceges-szures/">Céges szűrés</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/dijak/">gy.i.k</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/videok/">Videók</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/galeria/">Galéria</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a href="http://www.emotion-online.hu/levente/honti/rolunk/">Rólunk</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

what im missing?

Comment: I Think you forgot to associate the event mouseout with sliedeUp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stay in the scope of your element (by using $(this)).

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav.main_menu li").hover(function(){
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown(500);   
    },function(){
     $(this).children("ul").slideUp(300);      
    });
});
```

Comment: man thanks, it workd really thanks, i promise i will buy you a beer

Comment: will do just have to wait 6mins :)

Comment: That's fine! Good luck with scripting!